# Search data by taking input from datepicker in yii2

Tags: yii2

In this case the sql query in the search model is -

```
$query = (new Query())
    ->select (['billdate','billno','bills_partyname','billamount'])
    ->from('bills')
    ->where(['between', 'billdate', 'from_date', 'to_date']);
```

I've added a daterangepicker in the index.php file. The code is -

```
<?=  DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'from_date',
    'value' => '2014-01-01',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
    'name2' => 'to_date',
    'value2' => '2016-01-01',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ]
]);
?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PartiesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Parties model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

index.php looks like

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
//use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\ExpartiesSearch;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Parties';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="parties-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<!--     <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Parties', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p> -->
    <!-- <div class="custom-filter">

    Date range:
     <input name="start" />
     <input name="end" />

    </div> -->




<?= '<label class="control-label">Select Date Range</label>'; ?>
<?=  DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $searchModel,
    'attribute' => 'from_date',
    'value' => '2014-01-01',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
    'attribute2' => 'to_date',
    'value2' => '2016-01-01',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ]
]);
?>
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export' => false,
        'columns' => [
        // [
        //     'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
        //     'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
        //         return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
        //     },
        //     'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
        //         $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
        //         $searchModel-> parties_district = $model['district'];
        //         $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        //         return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
        //             'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        //             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //             ]);                   

        //         },
        //     ], 
            // 'district', 
            // 'sell',
            // 'collection',
        'billdate',
        'billno',
        'bills_partyname',
        'billamount',

        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

This is not working. Please tell me what needs to be done.

Comment: please give your `index.php` GridView::widget() code

Comment: already given above

Comment: show classname your DatePicker. which extension of use?

Comment: @Vitaly didn't get you. Please tell me what details you want.

Comment: DatePicker widget form Yii framwork or other extension?

Comment: this? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html

Comment: I'm using kartik datepicker - http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker

Comment: I'm using kartik datepicker - demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker

Comment: This is an example of what you want to do http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/64082-yii2-gridview-filter-by-date-range/

Comment: @shoara - in the forum epulgaron wants to use the daterange in the gridview. But in my case I have added a daterangepicker separately and want to use it separately. Because I have two subqueries in which I want to use the same daterange and later join it. That's why I cannot use it in the gridview and added separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somthing like this

In View before GridView

```
<?php

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'get',
    'enableClientScript' => false
]);

?>
<?= '<label class="control-label">Select Date Range</label>'; ?>
<?=  DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $searchModel,
    'attribute' => 'from_date',
    'value' => '2014-01-01',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
    'attribute2' => 'to_date',
    'value2' => '2016-01-01',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ]
]);
?>

<?php echo Html::submitButton('Search') ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In Controller

```
public function actionIndex(){

    $searchModel = new PartiesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->get());

    return $this->render('index', compact('dataProvider', 'searchModel'));
}
```

In Your Search Model

```
class PartiesSearch extends Parties
{
    public $from_date;
    public $to_date;


    //add rule

    public function rules(){
        return [
            //... your rules,
            [['from_date', 'to_date'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    //... some code

    public function search($params = []){

        $query = (new Query())
            ->select (['billdate','billno','bills_partyname','billamount'])
            ->from('bills');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query
        ]);

        if( !($this->load($params) && $this->validate()) ){
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if($this->from_date && $this->to_date)
            $query->where(['between', 'billdate', $this->from_date, $this->to_date]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: getting Undefined variable: searchModel in Gridview widget line - 'filterModel' => 'searchModel',

Comment: change to `'filterModel' => $searchModel`

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a typo. It's already 'filterModel' => $searchModel

Comment: Undefined variable: model 
line - $dataProvider = $model->search(\Yii::$app->request->get());

Comment: syntax error, this right `$searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->get());`

Comment: Getting unknown property: frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch::from_date

Comment: add 2 public attributes `from_date` and `to_date`, see my updated answer

Comment: Now I'm getting the the data but nothing happens if I change the dates. I'm getting the whole data in the database table - not giving data between the dates

Comment: Form send method POST or GET ?

Comment: Please, add your `index` view file with form in question.

Comment: I've added the index.php in the question

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from_date is come by post/Get method Try this

```
$query = (new Query())->select (['billdate','billno','bills_partyname','billamount'])->from('bills')->where(['between', 'billdate', $_POST['from_date'], $_POST['to_date']]);
```

Comment: can you give me your controller code or you check by echo print what exactly come after submitting data

Answer (score 0):

You are not using model to create date range picker so either use model or change name from

```
'name' => 'from_date'
```

to

```
'name' => 'PartiesSearch[from_date]'
```

*and similar for to_date

Comment: add your search function

Comment: Or add `'model' => $searchModel`  option in DatePicker config and override `name` `name2` to `attribute` `attribute2`

Comment: @Vitaly - You mean add 'model' => $searchModel, before 'name' => 'from_date',? and change name name2 to attribute attribute2?

Comment: @KandarpPatel - I've already given the search function in the question.

Comment: @Tanmay IS IT SO ? Where exactly it is in question ?

Comment: @KandarpPatel - didn't get you. You want the SearchModel. Right?